# Scrapy Selenim not extracting data from all start_urls

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

The code below extracts the data as it should if only one url is listed. If I enter two urls (as below), it extracts data only from the first url - but twice! Any idea how to overcome this? Note that I deleted some selectors to shorten the code.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium import webdriver

class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "match_summary"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.flashscore.com/match/v5GmqsWa/#match-summary',
            'https://www.flashscore.com/match/Wju9nz58/#match-summary',]

        for url in urls:
            yield SeleniumRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.detailMS__incidentRow'):
            yield {'Match': response.selector.xpath('//title/text()').getall(),
                   'Round': response.selector.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/a/text()').getall(),
                   'Date': response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="utime"]/text()').getall(),
                   'Time': quote.css('div.time-box::text').extract(),
                   'OverTime': quote.css('div.time-box-wide::text').extract()}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you actually run the functions from this class? I tried to look at your problem but I don't know enough to replicate your issue with the information given.

Comment: The code that I copied is part of the Scrapy project (spider), that one needs to create. The scraping is then run through the command line (for example, "scrapy crawl match_summary"). Don't know exactly which part of the Scrapy project calls this function, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Please NOTE : Do not give your class the name `Spider` , it conflicts with the `library's Spider class` and may confuse your script.

Have you tried using `start_urls` instead of the `start_requests` approach ?

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'match_summary'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.flashscore.com/match/v5GmqsWa/#match-summary',
        'https://www.flashscore.com/match/Wju9nz58/#match-summary',]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.detailMS__incidentRow'):
        yield {'Match': response.selector.xpath('//title/text()').getall(),
               'Round': response.selector.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/a/text()').getall(),
               'Date': response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="utime"]/text()').getall(),
               'Time': quote.css('div.time-box::text').extract(),
               'OverTime': quote.css('div.time-box-wide::text').extract()}
```

Comment: The pages need to be opened through SeleniumRequest otherwise it doesn't work (don't know the details of web technologies behind it).